# I should have the FW block all the traffic unless its from specific Specific IP addresses, GCloud L7 LB -> GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, cloudflare

We are using L7 to point K8S.

I would like to proxy the traffic via CloudFlare.

I should have the FW block all the traffic unless its from specific CF IP addresses.
How can I do this?

Comment: can you provide more details or clarifications such as your infrastructure (Are you using GKE? Are you using a GCE LB?) and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Based on what you have so far, I believe you are using GKE + GCE L7 LB and you want to all traffic to go through CloudFlare first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#configuring_security_policies_for_https_load_balancing) to attach policies for incoming requests at HTTP(S) load balancer level.

Is not specified in your question description, but if you're using a GKE cluster with a [GCE ingress class](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress), you can also attach these policies to it [following this guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-armor-backendconfig).